# OpenCV Face Recognition : [iOS]

Tags: ios, objective-c, opencv

I am trying to work on OpenCV Face recognition but the problem is :-

The sample code i downloaded from github(https://github.com/ekurutepe/iOS-OpenCV-FaceRec) for opencv face recognition have the following problem :-

```
use of undeclared identifier createLBPHFaceRecognizer()
```

Please refer to the following screenshot :-

[image]

Comment: Can you post the github link which you download that project on?

Comment: https://github.com/ekurutepe/iOS-OpenCV-FaceRec

Answer (score 0):

I've been faced with this issue. The latest pod opencv library does not contain "extra" libs (e.g. face detection). So you have to find or build library with required library by yourself